# What could be causing a React app to behave differently in Vite dev server vs Vite build/preview?

Tags: reactjs, vite

My understanding is that the only major difference between the dev server and a build is that Rollup handles the bundling but esbuild is still doing all the transpilation-related tasks either way.

The issues seem to all relate to url/history/routing areas. Using `vite`, pushing a change to the url did not cause the `useHistory` hook to re-render the component. With `vite build` it does re-render. (Although the `useLocation` hook DID work running `vite`)

With `vite` a particular component that uses params pulled out of the url immediately unmounts itself causing a redirect. With `vite build` it works just fine.

My goal here is to maybe get some direction on what to even start to look at because I'm not able to even theorize as to if this could possibly be a code issue, some config problem, or what.

Probably relevant packages:

```
"history": "^4.10.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"vite": "^4.4.9",
```

`vite.config.ts`

```
export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  // Load env file based on `mode` in the current working directory.
  // Set the third parameter to '' to load all env regardless of the `VITE_` prefix.
  const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), "")
  return {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "../../theme.config": path.join(__dirname, "src/semantic-ui/theme.config"),
        yup: "yup/index.js",
      },
    },

    plugins: [
      react(),
      viteTsconfigPaths(),
      nodePolyfills(),
    ],
    build: {
      outDir: "build",
    },
    server: {
      host: env.HOST,
      port: Number(env.PORT ?? 5000),
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        less: {
          math: "always",
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```

Development OS is MacOS Ventura 13.5.2.
Everything also works correctly when `vite build` on our CI, which is an Alpine Linux image.

Comment: Can you add operating system and/or docker setup? File change detection might be relevant.

Comment: @cmonkey Updated with the info